# Why when mypy needs type annotation, stupid annotation deals with the error?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Mypy is erroring on this line:

```
response = {'available_fields': []}

error: Need type annotation for 'response'
```

When I add stupid annotation that response is a dict, the error disappears:

```
response: typing.Dict = {'available_fields': []}
```

So, I have some questions about it. Why stupid annotation deals with error? How to tune mypy (configs, options, etc.) not to worry about this line without annotation?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that mypy has no idea what your list is supposed to contain. Is it a list of strings? A list of ints? Something else?

When you do something like...

```
response: Dict = {'foo': []}
```

...mypy will automatically fill in the missing type parameters for dict with [`Any`, the dynamic type](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dynamic_typing.html). So, the above declaration is exactly equivalent to doing:

```
response: Dict[Any, Any] = {'foo': []}
```

That is, your key can be literally anything (not just a string), and the value can also be anything (not just a list).

---

In your case, you should probably either (a) fill in the expected key and value types in your annotation:

```
# For example:
response: Dict[str, List[str]] = {'foo': []}
```

...or (b), use [TypedDict](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict) if your dict is more complicated.

---

If you want mypy to disallow you from omitting parameters in generic types (e.g. forbid doing just `response: Dict = ...`), use the [`--disallow-any-generics` command line flag](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#disallow-dynamic-typing). You can also add this option to a [config file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html), if you don't want to type out the flag every time you run mypy.

Comment: Is there an option which will suppress mypy error on line without annotation? Preferable in config file. I want the line `response = {'available_fields': []}` to be valid for mypy without any modifications in source code.

Comment: @Sanya -- If the var is declared in the global scope, use the `--allow-untyped-globals` flag/config option. If it's defined inside of a function, probably the best you can do is to either remove all type hints from that function's params (making it dynamically typed) or suppress the error by adding a [`# type: ignore` comment](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#spurious-errors-and-locally-silencing-the-checker) to that line. Note that none of these options make that line "valid" -- rather, they're more like mechanisms that make mypy less accurate in detecting type errors.

Comment: That said, I would personally recommend adding accurate annotations whenever possible/be cautious about using these options. The whole point of mypy is to try and take advantage of type inference to detect as many errors as possible, and to do that you'll sometimes need to give mypy hints for cases where it can't infer certain types. Lowering the accuracy of mypy is sometimes necessary (especially when migrating large codebases to using types), but it should be avoided when possible.